# Eloquent has() method counts soft deleted rows

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

using

```
$users = User::has('comments','>=',3);
```

in Laravel 5.6 returns users with more than 3 comments but counts soft deleted comments, while I want the list of users who have more than 3 active comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find the reason but creating a second relation solved my problem:

```
public function active_comments(){
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class)->where('deleted_at',null);
    }
```

and then

```
$users = User::has('active_comments','>=',3);
```